# Do I get back all the search engine rankings I had after having blocked a domain using robots.txt?

Tags: seo, search-engines, robots.txt, ranking, disallow

I blocked Google from crawling my domain using a robots.txt rule

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

by mistake. Just recently I noticed, two months later, and I removed the robots.txt file. The website was previously well ranked for certain queries. Now it is obviously not, with most webpages having disappeared.

Will I take a permanent hit on my rankings because of this? How much time should I expect it will take to recover it? Is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

- Whether you will take a permanent hit or not can't be said with 100% guarantee since Google does what Google wants. However, from what you've described, I don't see a reason they would permanently penalize you (**this is my professional opinion, not a promise nor based on Google's input**).
- As for the time it would take to recover there can't be guarantees either since for the same reason as above.
- You can ask google to scan your site and get back to working on a good backlink profile. As well as making sure there are signals (such as mentions of the site, and social media links etc.) that show that someone cares about your site.

Best of luck!